# Setting up a Playlist to Automatically Remove Played Podcasts on the iPod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I have my play lists setup on my computer to automatically remove played podcasts from my play list (Play Count = 0). However, I want the same behavior on my iPod Touch. I have occasionally gotten this to work, but have been unable to figure out the trick to get it work when I want it to.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about smart playlists. I don't believe live updating on an iPod will happen for smart playlists which rely on other smart playlists that are NOT on the iPod. I have one smart playlist which contains all my podcasts, based on genre and some other criteria, and feeds all other podcast smart playlists. If I don't include that smart playlist (and all the other ones used to build the final playlists)...I don't believe my other playlists will update until I re-sync with iTunes.

I went to [iLounge](http://www.ilounge.com/) to find something in the forums to confirm my post and I found [this](http://forums.ilounge.com/showthread.php?t=248088&highlight=live+updating). It confirms my thought and also indicates that the new OS 3.0 breaks live updating for any smart playlist which relies on another smart playlist.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you Check the "Live updating" box.
This tells the ipod to update the playlist when something changes (in your case, the play count).

Comment: I don't think that the iPod touch updates play lists as you go. From my experience, changes to play lists on the iPod only occur when syncing to iTunes.

Comment: This issue was fixed in OS 3.0.  Took them long enough to do it, too :\

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a playlist, you can also manage the device itself which seems more effective to me.  If you click on the device it will have a podcast tab.  There you can select the podcasts you wish to sync or sync all and there is a pulldown selector where you can select "Sync Unplayed".  Click Apply down at the bottom right and Voila! That should be it.

Comment: I am subscribed to about 125 podcasts. I learned that long ago. What I am looking for is something to make it easier to know where I ended. NOTE: I don't always start the play list in the beginning.